# How to parse a PKCS12 file programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, keystore, pkcs#12

How to parse a PKCS12 file programmatically in Java?

When I tried to use KeyStore APIs in the my program, I got an "No Such Algorithm Exception" while decrypting Authsafe.

But, apart from using KeyStore, is there any other way to parse PKCS12 in Java?

Comment: What works with `keytool` should work with the Java API directly. How are you trying to use it?

Comment: @Bruno, I am sorry. I made a mistake. It is not working with Keytool also. How to find out which all algorithms are supported by the provider?

Comment: Assuming you're using the Sun provider (default): http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html . (It would help if you posted a fragment of code explaining what you're trying to do in more details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Bouncy Castle JAVA Api](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).

Here's an [example](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/bouncycastle/jce/examples/PKCS12Example.java.html) for PKCS 12